# Method inside method c# (Xamarin)

Tags: java, c#, android

i am using a google guide to create place suggestions in my Android app made with Xamarin. I was wondering how would you convert this Java code to c#, and how to deal with the methods inside a method in c#? Thanks!

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                filterResults.values = resultList;
                filterResults.count = resultList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }};
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: I tried the nested class method... The problem is I have to implement PerformFiltering from a class inheriting from Filter, AND need to call the:
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
But If i try to do it inside the nested Filter class, i get a
"Error CS0038: Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'Android.Widget.BaseAdapter' via nested type '...PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.SuggestionsFilter' (CS0038) "
Btw I am following this guide: https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android, so

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new named class extending or implementing `Filter` (depending on whether it's an interface or a class). Make it a nested class if you don't need it elsewhere.

For *single-method* interfaces, normally a delegate is the simplest way of representing the type - an idiom which Xamarin uses, I believe - and then you can use lambda expressions or anonymous methods to write the implementation "inline".

Comment: So, how would you use the delegate here, just write delegate in front of the whole method inside Filter?

Comment: @whitelatino: I wouldn't use a delegate here, given that there are two methods (`performFiltering` and `publishResults`). And no, you don't just put the word `delegate` in front. If you're new to C#, I would *strongly* advise you to learn the basics of the language in a regular console environment before you start trying to tackle Xamarin, which brings its own separate challenges. The more confident you are in C# as a language, the easier you'll find it.

Comment: I am not new to c#, but haven't used delegates much. Can you give me a couple of lines of code as a hint, and i will get it.

Comment: @whitelatino: Well as I've said, you wouldn't use a delegate here anyway. Just create a new class which extends/implements `Filter`.